# Use of dictionaries with lists in Python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I look for similar keys in a Python dictionary and that its values are saved in a single key by using a list? That is, for example, the user enters a name and two different phone numbers; I'd like to store those two telephone numbers in the same key.

```
agenda = {}

for i in range(3):
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre de usuario: ")
    numero = int(input("Ingrese el numero de telefono del usuario: "))
    agenda[nombre] = numero

for key in agenda.keys():
    if key in agenda.keys():
        lista = []
        agenda[key] = lista.append(numero)
print(agenda)
```

I tried it this way but if there is any repeated name the dictionary only takes into account once beforehand. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is hard to tell what exactly you want. Please provide some sample data show some code you have tried that is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean this

```
agenda = {}
for i in range(3):
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre de usuario: ")
    numero = int(input("Ingrese el numero de telefono del usuario: "))
    if nombre not in agenda:
        agenda[nombre] = []
        
    agenda[nombre].append(numero)
```

Example run:

```
>>> Ingrese el nombre de usuario: Pablo
>>> Ingrese el numero de telefono del usuario: 123
>>> Ingrese el nombre de usuario: Pablo
>>> Ingrese el numero de telefono del usuario: 456
>>> Ingrese el nombre de usuario: Camilo
>>> Ingrese el numero de telefono del usuario: 321
```

Now, if you print `agenda`, you get

```
>>> agenda
    {'Pablo': [123, 456], 'Camilo': [321]}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @Camilo's answer, you could make use of the defaultdict module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create a list by default. Additionally, you could check for repeated phone numbers.

```
from collections import defaultdict

agenda = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(3):
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre de usuario: ")
    numero = int(input("Ingrese el numero de telefono del usuario: "))
    if numero not in agenda[nombre]:
        agenda[nombre].append(numero)
```